# SQL Injection can occur here with Yii execute()?

Tags: yii, sql-injection

I've seen the following code:

```
$id = $_GET["user"]; 
 $auth = $_GET["id"]; 
 $sql = 'DELETE FROM categories where user_id = '.$id.' and category_id = '.$auth;          
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

I've been told that this code isn't ok, because it couldn't allow sql injection.

Is it because of the $_GET not being properly filtered ?

Wouldn't the Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute(); avoid that ?

Or when we arrive there, we **should** already check the data that is placed on the where clause ?

Comment: Do you have ActiveRecord models for your database tables? If not, why not? You could sidestep the whole SQL injection issue since with ActiveRecord you do not write queries yourself.

Comment: I found them easy to read then with a lot of wrappers around the queries and some extra options, at least that's how I saw them on Zend. Still a good point of course, however, as a matter of preference, I would prefer to write queries on a way that feels more natural to me.

Comment: I recommend reading this Wiki article about [How to write secure Yii applications](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first rule of data security for Web application is to never "trust" GET/POST parameters.

Your code is not attempting to "sanitize" the two GET parameters which your are building an SQL statement with.   This means someone can manipulate the URL to "inject" a second (or more) SQL statement into what your are executing. The best way to avoid SQL injection attacks is to use queries that "bind" their parameters thus ensuring you can only be running a single query.  The yii documentation on how to use bound parameters is available at the following URL (item #5)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao